# objective-C - add commas to CONTAINS condition in NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, contains

Here is the situation. I have some Core Data data and I want to get the data where a certain column (type) contains a variable. But not just the variable, it has to be:
,variable,

This is my current code:

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type CONTAINS ',%@,'", typeBar];
```

That doesn't work: it returns nil each time. 
If I do:

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type CONTAINS ,%@,", typeBar];
```

It flat out tells me it can't parse this format.
And finally if I do:

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type CONTAINS %@", typeBar];
```

It works but obviously without the commas that I need to check for too...

I hope the question was clear enough.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the commas before substituting, like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type CONTAINS %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@,",typeBar]];
```